# Why $G/N$ is discrete?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/mat1197/notes.pdf). On page 15, Line -5, why $G/N$ is discrete? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be profinite (let $G$ be as "above") ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I think that $G$ is a topological group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since by assumption $N$ is open, singletons in $G/N$ are open (the preimage of the singleton under the projection is a coset of $N$, and cosets of open sets are open), hence every subset of $G/N$ is open (as a union of singletons, which are open), so $G/N$ is a discrete space.

---

Alternative, more verbose explanation:

The quotient $G/N$ is endowed with the quotient topology, that means a subset $A \subset G/N$ is open if and only if $\rho^{-1}(A)$ is open in $G$, where $\rho \colon G \to G/N$ is the canonical homomorphism.

$\rho^{-1}(A)$ is a union of cosets of $N$, $$\rho^{-1}(A) = \bigcup_{x\in \rho^{-1}(A)} x\cdot N.$$

$N$ is open by assumption, and the translations are homeomorphisms in a topological group, hence $\rho^{-1}(A)$ is open in $G$ for every $A\subset G/N$, so every subset of $G/N$ is open.